# Read UID On NFC tag then write in the same time in one function ( Swift )

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to Read UID On NFC tag Then if The UID On my database Write on the tag If not Dont Write on it but in one function On Swift

Comment: This is very hard to understand because it lacks context and also because of the acronyms being used but it doesn't look like a question to me, more like a request. Please use the Help Center to familiarise yourself with what kind of questions can be asked and how to ask them.

Comment: you know The NFC business card like popl ... didnt active any NFC tag to active popl NFC you should use their app of popl each app active their own NFC tag  .. i want to know how is it work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.